# Multiple condition in Bash for loop to get unique output

Tags: linux, bash, for-loop, automation, pattern-matching

hope everyone fine. I am stacked badly so need your help

I am using a for loop to collect all folder names

```
for tamplate in /root/tool/nuclei-templates/*/
do 
    echo $tamplate
done
```

Output

```
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/brute-force/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/cves/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/dns/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/files/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/generic-detections/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/panels/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/payloads/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/security-misconfiguration/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/subdomain-takeover/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/technologies/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/tokens/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/vulnerabilities/
/root/tool/nuclei-templates/workflows/
```

I am using this output on a tool that need those folder path. That tool also give output like this

```
nuclei -l url.txt -t /root/tool/nuclei-templates/brute-force/ -o result.brute-force
```

Output

```
result.brute-force
```

But as i am using a for loop to automate this scan part i also need to generate unique output for each result.

I am expecting a output like this

```
result.brute-force
reesult.cves
result.dns
result.files
```

Generally for each tamplate load with for loop it should generate a output with the name of that specific tamplate folder.
If everything work well this should give me 13 unique result with that output pattern i mentioned.

Comment: Btw: Replace `$(ls -d /root/tool/nuclei-templates/*/)` with `/root/tool/nuclei-templates/*/`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question. Is there a reason why you don't `for tamplate in /root/tool/nuclei-templates/*/; do nuclei -l url.txt -t $tamplate -o result.$tamplate; done`?

Comment: I have tried but it give me error like this 
Could not create output file 'result./root/tool/nuclei-templates/workflows/

From this error i can understand that tool taking it as a directory and i need to output the last path name only not the entire path.

Comment: I see, then try `basename` to remove the first part of the path, lik this: `for tamplate in /root/tool/nuclei-templates/*/; do nuclei -l url.txt -t $tamplate -o result.$(basename $tamplate); done`

Comment: Wow. worked awesome for me. can you enter it as answare so i can confirm your ans